# Is possible this robot arm cut well around this plastic plate?

Tags: robotic-arm

Good Afternoon.

I am trying my best to put this Omron Viper 850 6-axis robot arm, to cut around some car plast plates.

The Viper 850 robot is this:

[image]

The car plastic plate that supposedly it to cut around, is this:

[image]

I`ve tried do it by programming in the robot software, inserting coordinates and positioning the robot, but it went far from the perfection, as you can see:

[image]

Therefore, I am trying just now to discover a best way to do this.

I though I could get a 3D model with g-code coordinates from a photo of the plate.

With the g-code in hands, I could take the current coordinate point, and the next coordinate point, make some calcs and get the adjust angle of the robot spindle cutter. Further, I might make a program to translate g-code to the programming language of the robot (eV+ language), with the due calculations already done.

But I think G-code generators doesn`t generate coordinate points in a ordered way. This is the first problem.

The second problem would be to adjust the angle of the Z-Axis.

Obs: The software that came with the robot not import drawings to robot cut.

Then, after all, my question: Is it possible to do with this robot? If no, why?

Comment: How many plastic parts are the same? 100s? 1000s? More? Or is each one unique?

Comment: You can use intel realsense cameras to get a point cloud of the object. There is also a zed stereolabs 3d camera that can export point clouds. You could then create an STL or OBJ of the model and then import into 3d printer software. Either way, you need another imaging tool to to extract the 3D information you need.

Comment: @50k4 Hi... here in the workshop there are 4 different models... But is needed a solution that fits all models. Will cut thousands plates of each type.

Comment: How do you position the part? Is there a reference geometry somewhere? Centering pins? Something else to assure that each part can be positioned under the robot exactly the same way?